# How can I 'force' the use of the const accessor in the assert?

Tags: c++, constants

*My google-fu did not allow me to find anything regarding this, so here I am asking.*

I've run my c++ code through *cppcheck*, and it reported that some code in an `assert` call might have potential side effects. I've reproduced at a smaller scale the issue:

```
struct Obj
{
  int* myInt;

  Obj() : myInt( new int(3) ) {}
  ~Obj() { delete myInt; }

  const int* getInt() const { return myInt; }
};

struct C
{
  Obj* myObj;

  C() : myObj( new Obj() ) {}
  ~C() { delete myObj; }

  const Obj* getObj() const { std::cout << "const" ; return myObj; }
        Obj* getObj()       { std::cout << "non const" ; return myObj; }
};

int main()
{
  C c;

  assert( c.getObj()->getInt() ); // Outputs "non const"
  return 0;
}
```

([Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c2fea5d9225d79c))

*cppcheck* is right, here: the `getObj()` method used is not the `const` one, it's the non-const one.

The goals are to 1) satisfy cppcheck and 2) make sure there are no side effects in these asserts.

How could I tell the compiler to use the `const` version instead of the non-const getter?

---

I have though about one way to achieve this but I find it very unclean, and I'd rather use the more conventional way to do this in this context: `const_cast` the base object.

```
assert( const_cast<const C&>(c).getObj()->getInt() );
```

Comment: You have a non-const object so it will prefer the non-const function.  Only way to change that is to remove the overload or use a const object

Comment: You can use `static_cast` instead of `const_cast`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the information! So I guess here, casting as a const is kind of the way to go.

Comment: @super It seems to be working, but is it cleaner than a `const_cast`?

Comment: [std::as_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Since `const_cast` is the only cast that can remove `const` or `volatile` it's usually reserved for that specific use case. Seeing a `static_cast` would be more natural to me and not flag any *hey, what going on here...* in my head.

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt - "but is it cleaner than a const_cast?" - Almost *anything* is cleaner than a `const_cast` (except for `reinterpret_cast` and the babies it can make *with* `const_cast` - C-style cast I'm looking at you).

Answer (score 1):

Since c is not const:

```
C c;
c.getObj();
```

Executes the non-const version. In C++17 there is `std::as_const()` which you can use:

```
assert( std::as_const(c).getObj()->getInt() );
```

which is slightly better than your suggested:

```
assert( const_cast<const C&>(c).getObj()->getInt() );
```

You can implement your own as_const, if c++17 is not available, and use it in your
assert statement:

```
template <class T>
const T & as_const(T& obj) 
{
    return obj;
}
template <class T>
void as_const(const T&& obj) = delete;
```

And use it:

`assert(::as_const(c).getObj()->getInt() );`

Must add the :: prefix to avoid ambiguity with std::as_const due to ADL for objects in std namespace.

Comment: You don't need a `const_cast` for adding `const`.  Just having `const` in the return type is sufficient to make `return obj;` do the right thing.

Comment: Right. I'll fix

Comment: Your `as_const` won't return a `const` reference since `T` is deduced as `U&`, and accepting rvalue references is a bug.

Comment: Why add_const_t<T>& is required for the return type? Why isn't it enough to return const T&?